# jaxb class binding for group declaration

Tags: jaxb, xsd

Can any one help me on how to 
create class for a group declaration using jaxb binding ?
I want to map a group in my xsd to a class which will be inherited by another class.I am stuck at how to map the group in xsd to a class using jaxb binding.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Please post some code and show us how far you've gotten and where you are stuck.